# .Net Core Forgot password not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am following the tutortial for [.Net core Account and password recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and I am not sure how things work. The tutorial says to add the email service in startup.cs then everything just started to work. I have no idea where the forgot password page is located, it not with the other pages, I checked hidden files and the actual directory it self (see image), yet I am being redirected there from the reset password link. I have no idea how the email service is being called yet I can set a break point and see that it is being hit with the correct data. I can see the sql query used to get the user information. Is this functionality managed by core identity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea where the forgot password page is located, it not with the other pages

You need Scaffold Identity in your ASP.NET Core project.

1. That means you need to add the pages you need through Scaffold Identity: **ForgotPassword, ForgotPasswordConfirmation, ResetPassword, ResetPasswordConfirmation**.
2. **[Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization)**

> I have no idea how the email service is being called yet I can set a break point and see that it is being hit with the correct data.

> Is this functionality managed by core identity?

**IEmailSender** is in the package **ASP.NET Core Identity.UI**, **with the default implementation** injected in DI that **doesn't do anything**.

I will explain in detail below how to send an email to reset the password. You can read the process of resetting the password first to the last.

1. In other words, you need to **Implement IEmailSender**.
2. In the link you gave, **it has been given in detail** how to **implement IEmailSender**.
3. In the example, **SendGrid** email provider is used. You can also choose other email providers.

   1. You need to register a SendGrid account first, then create an API Key, and store your SendGrid information in appsettings.json.

      - You can create an API Key as follows.
      - [image]
   2. **appsettings.json**:

      1. **SendGridUser**:

         - It’s the account you registered with SendGird. For example, I registered with the email **xxx.test.com**, and **SendGridUser is xxx.test.com**.
      2. **SendGridKey**:

         - This is the API Key mentioned above.

      ```
      {
        ... ...
        "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "SendGridUser": "xxxx",
        "SendGridKey": "xxxxx"
      }
      ```
4. The **process of resetting the password** can be briefly summarized as follows:

   1. Request the **ForgotPassword** page after **clicking the link** to reset the password
   2. Enter your email address to reset the password
   3. If the email address you need to reset your password exists and has been confirmed, then the method **OnPostAsync** in **ForgotPassword** will send an email to your email address.

      - If you set a breakpoint in the **Execute method** in the implementation class **EmailSender of IEmailSender**, you can see the result of the email sent.
   4. You can open your mailbox to see the link to reset the password you received, then enter the reset password and submit the form.
   5. After the form is successfully submitted, it will request the **OnPostAsync method of ResetPassword**, and the processing will be redirected to the **ResetPasswordConfirmation page**.
5. **Result**

   [image]