# SendGrid doesn't want to send emails ASP .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sendmail, sendgrid

I am new to sending emails and I chose SendGrid for that. I ran through many tutorials, but it just doesn't want to send any email.
This is the code for my `sendEmail` controller:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnblockMe.Controllers
{
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
     
            public IActionResult SendEmail()
            {
                var apikey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("emailKey");
                var client = new SendGridClient(apikey);
                var from = new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com","Test");
                var to = new EmailAddress("test999@gmail.com","Test");
                var subject = "Sending EMAIL";
                var PlainTextContent = "asdadsasdadsad";
                var htmlcontent = "<strong>asdadsasd</strong>";
                var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail
                    (
                        from,
                        to,
                        subject,
                        PlainTextContent,
                        htmlcontent
                    );
                var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
                return Content(msg.ToString());
            }
        
    }
}
```

And in `view` I have something like this:

```html
<form> 
   ....
   <button type="submit" asp-controller="Email" asp-action="SendEmail">Unblock Me!</button>
</form>
```

I didn't make any change in Startup or something like that. Can anyone teach me how to make this thing work?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an exception? If not, your `response` object should contain details about why the call failed.

Comment: No expection is thrown but it just doesnt send the email

Comment: I am guessing the from address test@gmail.com is just something you put in here as an example right? because you just can't send through SendGrid with a random from address, needs to be from a domain you have configured in SendGrid. Also you are not awaiting the sending of the actual email, so you have no idea if this task is ever completed.

Comment: I think @ThomasSchmidt has hit the nail on the head.  You have to "pre-approve" your sending email address with SendGrid or everything will fail. Have you done this step?

Comment: I solved it now , thank you

Answer (score -1):

> I didn't make any change in Startup

You need to **implement IEmailSender** and **register** for the **service** of sending mail in **Starup**.

You can **[click on this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2174369.aspx)** to view an example I wrote earlier.

In addition, you can **[click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120669/net-core-forgot-password-not-found/68126806#68126806)** to help you understand **SendGrid**.

Comment: None of these links are about SendGrid which the original poster talks about.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt Have you checked the links I provided? Does the example in the links not use and explain SendGrid?